# Do I always need to move Database queries from the UI thread to a separate thread?

Tags: android, sqlite, background

This question comes from an issue I am having, or really confusion on something. So its frowned upon to query databases on the UI thread. But my issue is, what if what appears on the screen relies on what the result is. Should you still run it in the background, or should you halt the screens output until you know the info you need from the database?

Comment: You should never, ever, ever "halt the screen's output".

Comment: @Falmarri thank you for pointing that out. The answer below helps me get more answers on completely avoiding that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you should set it up is to use an `AsyncTask` to query the database, using the `doInBackground` method. Then use the `onPostExecute` method to update the UI. You can't update the UI on any other thread than the main thread.

Hope that makes sense. If not, here are a couple articles that might help:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1823692&seqNum=3

Best of luck!

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for the explanation and links. Gives me a great starting point to learning how to handle that situation.

Comment: You are welcome! You'll find that the `AsyncTask` works wonders for situations like this! They are fairly easy to implement and will improve your performance by more than you would expect! Have fun!